# Angular redefine route back

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular application. I am on page 1, click on any link and go to page 3, while on page 3, how do I make it so that when the user clicks the back button in the browser, he goes to the 2nd page and not the first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preventDefault and override browser's back button behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300727/how-to-preventdefault-and-override-browsers-back-button-behavior)

Comment: I believe you can't do that ...